# How to stop graph by making stacked-barchart using MpChart android

Tags: android, graph

> I am working on a project where I have to display data in graphical representation.For achieve this, I am using Mpchart library. According to my project requirement, I have to display every bar of barset on the same index according to that barset number but it is becoming stacked barchart that I dont want to have.

For example :-

```
ArrayList<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();
    labels.add("January");
    labels.add("February");
    labels.add("March");
    labels.add("April");
    labels.add("May");
    labels.add("June");
    labels.add("March");
    labels.add("April");
    labels.add("May");
    labels.add("June");

    // for create Grouped Bar chart
    ArrayList<BarEntry> group1 = new ArrayList<>();
    group1.add(new BarEntry(1f, 0));
    group1.add(new BarEntry(8f, 0));
    group1.add(new BarEntry(1f, 0));
    group1.add(new BarEntry(1f, 0));

    ArrayList<BarEntry> group2 = new ArrayList<>();
    group2.add(new BarEntry(2f, 1));
    group2.add(new BarEntry(2f, 1));
    group2.add(new BarEntry(2f, 1));
    group2.add(new BarEntry(2f, 1));

    ArrayList<BarEntry> group3 = new ArrayList<>();
    group3.add(new BarEntry(3f, 2));
    group3.add(new BarEntry(3f, 2));
    group3.add(new BarEntry(3f, 2));
    group3.add(new BarEntry(3f, 2));

    ArrayList<BarEntry> group4 = new ArrayList<>();
    group4.add(new BarEntry(4f, 3));
    group4.add(new BarEntry(4f, 3));
    group4.add(new BarEntry(4f, 3));
    group4.add(new BarEntry(4f, 3));

    ArrayList<BarEntry> group5 = new ArrayList<>();
    group5.add(new BarEntry(5f, 4));
    group5.add(new BarEntry(5f, 4));
    group5.add(new BarEntry(5f, 4));
    group5.add(new BarEntry(5f, 4));

    ArrayList<BarEntry> group6 = new ArrayList<>();
    group6.add(new BarEntry(6f, 5));
    group6.add(new BarEntry(6f, 5));
    group6.add(new BarEntry(6f, 5));
    group6.add(new BarEntry(6f, 5));

    ArrayList<BarEntry> group7 = new ArrayList<>();
    group7.add(new BarEntry(7f, 6));
    group7.add(new BarEntry(7f, 6));
    group7.add(new BarEntry(7f, 6));
    group7.add(new BarEntry(7f, 6));

    ArrayList<BarEntry> group8 = new ArrayList<>();
    group8.add(new BarEntry(8f, 7));
    group8.add(new BarEntry(8f, 7));
    group8.add(new BarEntry(8f, 7));
    group8.add(new BarEntry(8f, 7));

    ArrayList<BarEntry> group9 = new ArrayList<>();
    group9.add(new BarEntry(9f, 8));
    group9.add(new BarEntry(9f, 8));
    group9.add(new BarEntry(9f, 8));
    group9.add(new BarEntry(9f, 8));

    ArrayList<BarEntry> group10 = new ArrayList<>();
    group10.add(new BarEntry(10f, 9));
    group10.add(new BarEntry(10f, 9));
    group10.add(new BarEntry(10f, 9));
    group10.add(new BarEntry(10f, 9));

    BarDataSet barDataSet1 = new BarDataSet(group1, "Group 1");
    barDataSet1.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);
    barChart.isTransitionGroup();

    BarDataSet barDataSet2 = new BarDataSet(group2, "Group 2");
    barDataSet2.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);

    BarDataSet barDataSet3 = new BarDataSet(group3, "Group 3");
    barDataSet3.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);

    BarDataSet barDataSet4 = new BarDataSet(group4, "Group 4");
    barDataSet4.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);

    BarDataSet barDataSet5 = new BarDataSet(group5, "Group 5");
    barDataSet5.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);

    BarDataSet barDataSet6 = new BarDataSet(group6, "Group 6");
    barDataSet6.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);

    BarDataSet barDataSet7 = new BarDataSet(group7, "Group 7");
    barDataSet7.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);

    BarDataSet barDataSet8 = new BarDataSet(group8, "Group 8");
    barDataSet8.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);

    BarDataSet barDataSet9 = new BarDataSet(group9, "Group 9");
    barDataSet9.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);

    BarDataSet barDataSet10 = new BarDataSet(group10, "Group 10");
    barDataSet10.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);
```

> it makes the bars staked and same index bars overlap each other.

[image]

> how can I display them side by side.

I am using library Mpchart version 2.1.6

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I used version 2.1.6. Follow the given example:

```
BarChart barChart = (BarChart) findViewById(R.id.chart);

ArrayList<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();
    labels.add("January");
    labels.add("February");
    labels.add("March");
    labels.add("April");
    labels.add("May");
    labels.add("June");

    //for create Grouped Bar chart
    ArrayList<BarEntry> group1 = new ArrayList<>();
    group1.add(new BarEntry(4f, 0));
    group1.add(new BarEntry(8f, 1));
    group1.add(new BarEntry(6f, 2));
    group1.add(new BarEntry(12f, 3));
    group1.add(new BarEntry(18f, 4));
    group1.add(new BarEntry(9f, 5));

    ArrayList<BarEntry> group2 = new ArrayList<>();
    group2.add(new BarEntry(6f, 0));
    group2.add(new BarEntry(7f, 1));
    group2.add(new BarEntry(8f, 2));
    group2.add(new BarEntry(12f, 3));
    group2.add(new BarEntry(15f, 4));
    group2.add(new BarEntry(10f, 5));

    BarDataSet barDataSet1 = new BarDataSet(group1, "Group 1");
    barDataSet1.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);

    BarDataSet barDataSet2 = new BarDataSet(group2, "Group 2");
    barDataSet2.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);

    ArrayList<BarDataSet> dataset = new ArrayList<>();
    dataset.add(barDataSet1);
    dataset.add(barDataSet2);


    BarData data = new BarData(labels, dataset);
    barChart.setData(data);
    barChart.animateY(5000);
    barChart.getXAxis().setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
```